# can't change col type to factor upon loading

Tags: r, readr

For some reason, when I try to upload this large csv file it give the error below. Any ideas?

```
library(readr)
data2014 <- read_csv("data2014.csv", col_types = cols(
  Year = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Round = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Game = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Matchup = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Top_Seed = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Low_Seed = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Home_Court = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  On_Road = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Play = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Quarter = col_factor(levels, ordered = FALSE),
  Time = col_skip(),
  Minutes = col_integer(),
  Seconds = col_integer(),
  Away = col_character(),
  Away_Points_Added = col_integer(),
  Score = col_character(),
  Home_Points_Added = col_integer(),
  Home = col_character()
))
```

Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_, : Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=closure].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
library(readr)
data2014 <- read_csv("data2014.csv", col_types = cols(
  .default = "f",
  Time = col_skip(),
  Minutes = col_integer(),
  Seconds = col_integer(),
  Away = col_character(),
  Away_Points_Added = col_integer(),
  Score = col_character(),
  Home_Points_Added = col_integer(),
  Home = col_character()
))
```

Comment: It looks fine. I have used it this way `readr 1.3.1` and `R 3.4.4`. It also mentioned in the [documentation](https://readr.tidyverse.org/articles/readr.html#available-column-specifications)